# How to use models in a list when plotting stat_smooth function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot multiple models within a list. However while plotting I'm unable to change the formula to standard y ~ x notation so I get an error. This would be well explained through an example. How do I use the models for plotting?

```
xvar=1:100
yvar=(1:100+(1:100)^2)
df=data.frame(xvar,yvar)
## this works fine
ggplot(df, aes(x=xvar, y=yvar)) + geom_point(size = 1) + geom_smooth(data = df, method = "lm", aes(x=xvar,y=yvar), formula = as.formula(y ~ x), size = 1, se = FALSE, colour = "yellow")

models=list(
    lm(yvar~xvar, data = df),
    lm(yvar~I(xvar^2), data = df)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = xvar, y = yvar)) + geom_point(size = 1) + geom_smooth(data = df, method = "lm", aes(x=xvar,y=yvar), formula = as.formula(models[[1]]), size = 1, se = FALSE, colour = "yellow")

Warning messages:
1: 'newdata' had 80 rows but variables found have 100 rows 
2: Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
arguments imply differing number of rows: 80, 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you what you need?

```
library(ggplot2)

xvar=1:100
yvar=(1:100+(1:100)^2)
df=data.frame(xvar,yvar)
## this works fine
ggplot(df, aes(x=xvar, y=yvar)) + geom_point(size = 1) + geom_smooth(data = df, method = "lm", aes(x=xvar,y=yvar), formula = as.formula(y ~ x), size = 1, se = FALSE, colour = "yellow")

#name the models
models=list(
  m1 = lm(yvar~xvar, data = df),
  m2 = lm(yvar~I(xvar^2), data = df)
)
#use the name of the first model and then a formula
ggplot(df, aes(x = xvar, y = yvar)) + geom_point(size = 1) + geom_smooth(data = models[[c("m1","model")]], method = "lm", aes(x=xvar,y=yvar), formula = as.formula(y ~ x), size = 1, se = FALSE, colour = "yellow")
```